# Java Android - Trouble with New activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity

The problem is that when I click on the ListView the application just closes. I use BaseAdapter. I need to open a new Acitivty to show detailed information, and that this problem prevents me.
If i remove this code, it is not closed. Please help fix this problem, or can I have something wrong doing.

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                OnClickActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_RATING, rating2);
        in.putExtra(TAG_USER, name2);
        in.putExtra(TAG_DESC, desc2);
        in.putExtra(TAG_DATE, date2);
        in.putExtra(TAG_ID, postID);
        startActivity(in);
```

Full code:

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {


            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                String nickname = c.getString("nickname");
                String description = c.getString("description");
                products.add(new ItemInfo(nickname, description));

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) 
    {
         SetAdapter();
    }
}

public void SetAdapter()
{
    boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, products);
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) 
        {
            ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            int pos = lvMain.getPositionForView(view);
            test(pos);
        }
    });
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
}

public void test(int position)
{
    ItemInfo p = boxAdapter.getItem(position);

    String name2 = p.username;
    String desc2 = p.description;

    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            OnClickActivity.class);
    in.putExtra(TAG_USER, name2);
    in.putExtra(TAG_DESC, desc2);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

LogCat logs:

```
03-27 21:05:43.923: W/dalvikvm(2496): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4157dba8)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496): Process: com.example.warapp, PID: 2496
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.warapp/com.example.warapp.OnClickActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at com.example.warapp.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:125)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at com.example.warapp.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:102)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-27 21:05:43.923: E/AndroidRuntime(2496):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.warapp/com.example.warapp.OnClickActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` looks like the `Activity` isn't properly declared in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: Declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you add OnClickActivity to AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.warapp/com.example.warapp.OnClickActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Check your Manifest.xml, your IDE might have forgot to declare it in your Manifest.xml, or you post renamed it the wrong way.

Here's one of my declared activity in AndroidManifest.xml within the application tag:

```
<activity
android:name="CameraActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:label="CameraActivity"/>
```